# Display a Popup in woocommerce shop page only

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, woocommerce

I am trying to set a popup for newsletter subscription in WooCommerce Shop Page **Only** with the use of a Cookie.
The problem: Setting a cookie in Wordpress should be done in functions.php in which Conditional Tags won't run as mentioned here:  https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Conditional logic won't work if written straight into `functions.php` (because the query object isn't set up until `wp_query` hook) but will work if called on any hook in the shop page... like `woocommerce_sidebar` or others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you want to show popup or want to add any script to shop page only
>   then you have to use `is_shop()` conditional tag in `wp_head` or
>   `wp_footer` action.

Try this code

```
function subscription_footer()
{
    //for shop page only
    if (is_shop())
    {
        //if cookie does not exist/set then perform your stuff.
        if (!isset($_COOKIE['shop_subscribe']))
        {
            setcookie('shop_subscribe', 'yes', time() + (86400 * 30)); // 86400 = 1 day
            $_COOKIE['shop_subscribe'] = 'yes';
            //here you can write your html/js code for popup.
        }
    }
    //print_r($_COOKIE);
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'subscription_footer');
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*